# windows - Turn On MySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, windows

I am facing MySQL error when I run my bot program for the first time PC has turned on. Because MySQL has not turned on yet.
I want my program to 'automatically' turn it on.

Is it possible to turning on MySQL with python scripts?
I already search it and all questions and answers are UNIX based.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: Windows. @Avión I already has windows tag on my question.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-start-service.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use this: This calls the windows cmd system and runs `net start` to  start the mysql server.

```
import os
os.system("net start mysql")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\bin\\mysql.exe'])
```

Change the path to the proper one.